# Spring Reactive Web update method makes a new record instead of update the existing one

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

Currently I'm using Spring Webflux and MongoDB, along with a set of CRUD REST API.
So I have a service method that takes in an ID of an existing object, an updated object, then mapping the updated one's data into the existing one. Like here:

ServiceImpl.java

```
@Override
public Mono<Computer> update(String id, Computer computer) {
    return repo.findById(id)
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new Exception("COMPUTER_NOT_FOUND")))
            .map(c -> computer)
            .flatMap(repo::save);
}
```

My REST Controller method:
EnpointController.java

```
@PutMapping("/{id}")
public Mono<Computer> updateOneComputer(@PathVariable("id") String id,@Valid @RequestBody Computer parsedBody) {
    return computerService.update(id, parsedBody);
}
```

But the problem is: Instead of update, it makes a new record into db. I have try something like set individual field of the existed object with the update one. It works, updated the existing document, but not efficient. It's not a solution, especially with the embedded document in Mongo.
Like this:

```
@Override
public Mono<Computer> update(String id, Computer computer) {
    return repo.findById(id)
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new Exception("COMPUTER_NOT_FOUND")))
            .map(c -> {
                c.setFoo(computer.getFoo());
                c.setBar(computer.getBar());
                //and so on!
            })
            .flatMap(repo::save);
}
```

My entities

Computer.java

```
@Document(value = "computers")
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Computer extends BaseDocument {

    private String name;
    private String customerId;
    private String computerModel;
    private String computerSpecs;
    private String otherPart;
}
```

BaseDocument.java

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class BaseDocument {

    @Id
    private String id;
    @CreatedDate
    private Date createdDate;
    @LastModifiedDate
    private Date updatedDate;
    @CreatedBy
    private String createdBy;
    @LastModifiedBy
    private String updatedBy;
    private char deleted = 'N';
}
```

Please help and thanks in advance!

Comment: can you please post your entity class, and debug what ids your entities have/get

Comment: @ThomasAndolf hi. I have a breakpoint in my service method. And it got the right Id. [Here my debugging process](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/505006002932940802/686185220847697938/unknown.png). And I will edit my document entities in the main question.

Comment: How about: `c -> {computer.setId(id)}`

Comment: @Valijon lemme try it

Comment: @Valijon actually, it's working. But far from that, it's like: c -> {computer.setId(id); return computer;}

Comment: NIce. does it meets your requirements?

Comment: @Valijon yes. i thought it will take the "c" local variable to the flatMap, but in fact it takes what ever return in that map method. Please add a answer so that I can give u an upvote :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
.map(c -> {computer.setId(id); return computer;})
```